# How do I tell apt-get install to stop trying to setup openssh-server?

Tags: apt

I installed openssh-server via apt-get install and it failed during the setting up stage with an error from /usr/bin/ufc about a bad file descriptior.

Anyway, I did the setup (configuration) of openssh (ssh.service) manually, and that's all working.

However, apt-get whenever it is asked to do something will still try and setup openssh-server, for example:

```
adf@locutus$ sudo apt-get -y install fancontrol                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
fancontrol is already the newest version (1:3.6.0-7).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 324 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up openssh-server (1:8.4p1-4) ...
/usr/bin/ucf[734]: >&3 : bad file descriptor
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 installed openssh-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I tell apt-get (or dpkg?) to not bother trying to setup openssh-server anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete its post-installation script:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst
```

and then finish configuring pending packages (so that their status is updated — this will include `openssh-server` and any package which couldn’t be configured):

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

However this could be a bug, and since you’re helping test the next release of Debian (thanks!), it would be great if you could file a bug too:

```
reportbug ucf
```

(I think the bug is in `ucf`, not `openssh-server`.)

Comment: Have filed a bug report.

Comment: So a preferred way to me hacking the status file :)

Comment: Right, this is still a bit of a hack (deleting the postinst), but better than poking around `status` ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this as follows (warning, backup your status file first):

```
sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/status
/^Package: openssh-server
/^Status: install ok half-configured
```

Changing that line to:-

```
Status: install ok installed
```

`apt-get`/`dpkg` no longer tries to complete the installation.

Note: The issue may re-appear if openssh-server is upgraded.